# Angularfire2 error TS2305

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework

I'm new to the ionic framework world and now I'm trying to create a app for a schoolproject. 
To save data in the app I'll be using firebase (for the first time). I try to import Angularfire and FirebaseListObservable to my .ts file but i get this error message:

"TS2305:Module "'C:/Users/matss/myRecords/node_modules/angularfire2/index"' has no exported member 'AngularFire'.

Here's my import in app.module.ts

```
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2;

export const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "blablabla",
authDomain: "blablabla",
databaseURL: "blablabla",
projectId: "blablabla",
storageBucket: "blablabla",
messagingSenderId: "blablabla"
};
```

here's my code in excersises.ts, which gives the errormessage:

```
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';

  constructor(private navParams: NavParams, public nacCtrl: NavController, af: AngularFire){
this.records = af.database.list('/records');
```

}

As a rookie to this, I haven't found any "good" tutorials, I might use the wrong keywords in my searches..
But for this I followed this tutorial:
https://www.joshmorony.com/building-a-crud-ionic-2-application-with-firebase-angularfire/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your import line references AngularFire in the second block, which is not available.  I tried changing this to AngularFireModule (similar to the first block) but then my samples get FirebaseListObservable is not defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, however I was able to solve it. I read Josh's article, as I read all of his and he is really good, but recently AngularFire2 was updated from what I understand and that has caused a few changes.

How I solved it was like this:

```
import {AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';
```

I also imported `import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';` 
instead of 
`import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';`

From what I understand, they are modularising it a lot more so that people can use the functions they want and not have all the overhead. I might be wrong though.

This did work for me however.

So, with your code, it should now look like this:

In your app.module.ts file:

```
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
```

Then import it under the @NgModule tag imports like so:

```
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule 
]
```

Then under your component ts that you are working with. do the following:

```
import {AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';
```

Then later on you would need to declare it

```
records: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
```

In your constructor:

```
constructor(private navParams: NavParams, public nacCtrl: NavController, db: AngularFireDatabase){
    this.records = db.list('/records');}
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved that problem with imports! Now I got another problem though, in my .ts file:



 constructor(private navParams: NavParams, public nacCtrl: NavController, af: AngularFireDatabase){
    this.records = af.database.list('/records');
  }



The error I got i af.database.list and it says:

TS2339: Property 'list' doeas not exist on type 'Database'.

Comment: Inside your constructor. Change af: AngularFireDatabase property to db: AngularFireDatabase. Then instead of this.records = af.database.list('/records'); Do this.records = db.list('/records');

Comment: Here is the link to the changes for the new api set of AngularFire2 and Angular4 https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-4-upgrade.md

Comment: That got rid of my code errors thankfully. But when I run the app I'm getting console errors:

http://imgur.com/a/xDCap

Comment: I apologize, I noticed I skipped the app.module.ts section that is required. I included it in the answer now too.

Comment: Now the console error disappeared and I got to see my page for 1 second, then I got this error:
http://imgur.com/a/Srn2T

I would think it has something to do with my database at the firebase website?

Also, in my component ts file, the import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';  is an unused import? I might only need it in my app.module.ts ?

Comment: You are right, the AngularFireModule only needs to be called in the app.module.ts. As for the error you are getting. It is on Firebase rules side. You need to set authentication up on both your Firebase panel and inside the app, unless you dont want authentication. If you dont want authentication and just want to test to see if it works. Do this under Database Rules in Firebase {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth === null",
    ".write": "auth === null"
  }
}

Comment: Finally! Thank you, I'm now able to save things to the firebase database! I appreciate your help!

Comment: Anytime :) If you happy with it, just mark as correct answer :)