# Angularfire and FirebaseListObservable has no exported member angularfire2 using ionic 2 app

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

FirebaseListObservable and Angularfire has no exported member "angularfire2" when i am creating Ionic 2 app import both files in home.ts

My Cordova and ionic version is
Cordova version 6.5.0
Ionic Version 2.2.3
Node version 6.10.2
typings version 2.1.1
typescript version 2.3.2

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2';
@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, af:AngularFire ) {
}
}
```

Comment: What version of angularFire are you using? If it is 2.4+ you likely need to adjust your code as per this thread https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-4-upgrade.md

Comment: thankyou i am done to import AngularFireDatabase

Comment: Have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777706/angularfire2-index-has-no-exported-member-angularfire

Comment: Have a look at this-
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762494/angularfire2-error-ts2305

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is to simply change this line

```
import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2';
```

to

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from "angularfire2/database";
```

[*REFRENCE](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/1-install-and-setup.md)

Comment: yes i am done this before your answering. BTW thanks for your answer

Comment: Did they changed it yet again?! I'm getting this error for `FirebaseListObservable`. Which file should I import for that?

Comment: import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database'; still showing error in FirebaseListObservable

Answer (score 57):

As of AngularFire 2.0.4 and above `FirebaseListObservable` and `FirebaseObjectObservable` are now called `AngularFireList` and `AngularFireObject`.

Example:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
```

Answer (score 25):

Ashish Jha, You're right, as the new update uses AngularFirestore and it uses a simple Observable instead of FirebaseListObservable I wasn't able to import FirebaseListObservable and was struggling to do a push(). Changing

```
import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2';
```

to

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from "angularfire2/database-deprecated";
```

worked fine for me, thank you!

Comment: wow, I got the same problem I tried to using AngularFireList instead of using deprecated, but push method seems not friendly to me, the data type has problem I struggling 2 hours and just give up. Now I am gonna use deprecated. Now it's working.

Answer (score 9):

The solution that worked for me was to change this line

```
import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2';
```

to

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from "angularfire2/database-deprecated";
```

You can read more about it here https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 3):

`FirebaseListObservable` has been changed into `AngularFireList`.

simply use this to import

```
import { AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
```

Check migration doc [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md)

Answer (score 1):

Changing it to the following solved it for me:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
```