# Retrieving id in firebase database

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm currently trying to build somethin with googles firebase and I ran across a problem. It seems that this snippet of code

```
    export class FirebaseService {
    items: Observable<Item[]>;

    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase){

    }

    getBusinesses(){
        this.businesses = this.db.list('/items').valueChanges() as Observable<Item[]>
        return this.items;
    }

}
```

used to give you an object with $key as the key of the object in the database (at least that's what it did in a tutorial I read)

The problem is, that $key is undefined and i was wondering, how I'd get the list-method to return an object including the key. Been trying around for a while but I can't really find the error. Would be glad if someone knew the answer.

[edit]

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md
This brought me a little closer to the solution. It seems, angularfire2 has seen some major changes with version 5.0.0. But since im still learning, I can't really integrate it in my code. At the moment it looks like this

firebase.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Business} from '../Business';
import {Category} from '../Category';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {
    businesses : Observable<Business[]>;
    categories : Observable<Category[]>;

    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase){

    }

    getBusinesses(){
        this.businesses = this.db.object('/businesses').snapshotChanges().map(action => {
            console.log('ACTION:');
            console.log(action);
            const $key = action.payload.key;
            const data = {$key, ...action.payload.val()};
            return data;
        }) as Observable<Business[]>;
        return this.businesses;
    }
}
```

and app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { FirebaseService } from './services/firebase.service';
import { Business } from './Business';
import { Category } from './Category';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app';
    items: Observable<any[]>;
    businesses: Business[];
    categories: Category[];
    appState: string;
    activeKey: string;

    constructor(private _firebaseService: FirebaseService){

    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this._firebaseService.getBusinesses().subscribe(businesses => {
            console.log('Businesses:');
            console.log(businesses);
            this.businesses = businesses;
        });
    }


}
```

Now my result is not as i wished it was. Basically what I'm getting back is

```
{
    0: {
        Key01: "xyz",
        Key02: "yyy"
    },
    1: {
        Key11: "zyx",
        Key12: "zzz"
    },
    $key: "businesses"
}
```

I'll keep on trying. Maybe you know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for the help so far

[/edit]

Comment: replace .list() by .object() and you will get the object (and so the key with it)

Comment: unfortunately that didnt work. Still getting the object without the key

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the items as a `FirebaseListObservable<Item[]>` and do the getBusinesses() call like below:

```
this.items= this.af.list('/items') as FirebaseListObservable<Item[]>;
```

Hope this will help you get the $key value.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't import FirebaseListObservable. It's neither found in 'angularfire2' nor in 'agularfire2/database'. I'm using version 5.0.0. Should i be using another one?
[edit] It looks like I'm supposed to use an rxjs/Observable now as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43799052/angularfire-and-firebaselistobservable-has-no-exported-member-angularfire2-using this tells me that the FirebasListObservable is deprecated. :/

Comment: OK, I', one step closer. https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md
This gave a little more clarity, but I still can't figure out how to change my service and the app.component. I will edit my question because it's hard to describe it here